# SQL - How to split monthly data into weeks

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database planed sale for specific product is saved for every month in year. For other products plan is saved for every week of year.
I have to unify both plans to weeks. For monthly based plan I need to split it into weeks. I'm trying to split monthly data into weeks 
using weeks count in specific month and calculating weekly value, but i don't know how to get weekly table as a result. 
So using SQL how to convert this table

```
select 
   month, 
   value, 
   week_count, 
   round(value/week_count,0) weekly_value 
from 
   my_table

-=======T=======T=============T===============¬
¦ MONTH ¦ VALUE ¦  WEEK_COUNT ¦  WEEKLY_VALUE ¦
¦=======+=======+=============+===============¦
¦     1 ¦    20 ¦           4 ¦             5 ¦    
¦     2 ¦    28 ¦           4 ¦             7 ¦
¦     3 ¦    35 ¦           5 ¦             7 ¦
¦     4 ¦     8 ¦           4 ¦             2 ¦
¦     5 ¦    15 ¦           5 ¦             3 ¦
¦     6 ¦    24 ¦           4 ¦             6 ¦
¦     7 ¦    24 ¦           4 ¦             6 ¦
¦     8 ¦    20 ¦           5 ¦             4 ¦
¦     9 ¦    40 ¦           4 ¦            10 ¦
¦    10 ¦    48 ¦           4 ¦            12 ¦
¦    11 ¦    45 ¦           5 ¦             9 ¦
¦    12 ¦    36 ¦           4 ¦             9 ¦
L=======¦=======¦=============¦===============-
```

into this table:

```
-=======T=======¬
¦ WEEK  ¦ VALUE ¦
¦=======+=======¦
¦     1 ¦     5 ¦    
¦     2 ¦     5 ¦    
¦     3 ¦     5 ¦    
¦     4 ¦     5 ¦    
¦     5 ¦     7 ¦
¦     6 ¦     7 ¦
¦     7 ¦     7 ¦
¦     8 ¦     7 ¦
¦     9 ¦     7 ¦

...

¦    43 ¦    12 ¦
¦    44 ¦     9 ¦
¦    45 ¦     9 ¦
¦    46 ¦     9 ¦
¦    47 ¦     9 ¦
¦    48 ¦     9 ¦
¦    49 ¦     9 ¦
¦    50 ¦     9 ¦
¦    51 ¦     9 ¦
¦    52 ¦     9 ¦
L=======¦=======-
```

thanks for any advice.

Comment: this will never be accurate unless you have a column holding the exact date

Comment: Thanks, but accuracy is not the point. I will handle that later. First I need convert structure from months to weeks.

Comment: but weeks can be part of two different months

Comment: @KrzysztofKuczyński, I think the matter is not specifically about the precision but that this is counter-intuitive considering that Oracle have a ready solution to deal with that. Look at the documentation for extracting datetime information: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37483_01/server.751/es_eql/src/ceql_functions_date_extract.html

Comment: Hi @KrzysztofKuczyński do you have any code to show us? check [mcve]

Comment: Don't do this, you will generate a lot of trouble for yourself. Use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values and derive all information from there.

Comment: Try to get this problem as simple as it is, not to complicate it searching dates in it and calculating number of weeks in every month. Weeks in months are given. Lets assume than months and weeks are abstract scalars (it can be m months, and n weeks) not connected with dates.
Next we set (arbitraty) than specific month has own weeks number. I.E. We get 5 months and every has 3 weeks. 
Having every month assigned value of 15, every week will have value of 5. Littlefoot below has solved it, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option; see if it suits your needs.

```
SQL> with my_table (month, week_count, weekly_value) as
  2  (
  3   select 1,  4,  5 from dual union all
  4   select 2,  4,  7 from dual union all
  5   select 3,  5,  7 from dual union all
  6   select 4,  4,  2 from dual union all
  7   select 5,  5,  3 from dual union all
  8   select 6,  4,  6 from dual union all
  9   select 7,  4,  6 from dual union all
 10   select 8,  5,  4 from dual union all
 11   select 9,  4, 10 from dual union all
 12   select 10, 4, 12 from dual union all
 13   select 11, 5,  9 from dual union all
 14   select 12, 4,  9 from dual
 15  )
 16  select row_number() over (order by t.month) week,
 17         t.weekly_value
 18  from my_table t,
 19       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 20                           connect by level <= t.week_count
 21                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist ))
 22  order by 1;

      WEEK WEEKLY_VALUE
---------- ------------
         1            5
         2            5
         3            5
         4            5
         5            7
         6            7
         7            7
         8            7
         9            7
        10            7
        11            7
        12            7
        13            7
        14            2
        15            2
        16            2
        17            2
        18            3
        19            3
        20            3
        21            3
        22            3
        23            6
        24            6
        25            6
        26            6
        27            6
        28            6
        29            6
        30            6
        31            4
        32            4
        33            4
        34            4
        35            4
        36           10
        37           10
        38           10
        39           10
        40           12
        41           12
        42           12
        43           12
        44            9
        45            9
        46            9
        47            9
        48            9
        49            9
        50            9
        51            9
        52            9

52 rows selected.

SQL>
```